# Safari and $(window).on('scroll')

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

It seems like in Safari ( ver: 9.1 ), neither jQuery nor vanilla JavaScript catches the scroll event.

My goal is to catch the scroll position and if it is below 50px, fix the nav bar by adding a class, and otherwise remove that class.

The code snippet I placed below works in Chrome, Firefox and IE but not in Safari.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop()>50 ){
        $('.navbar').addClass('nav-fixed');
    } 
    else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same thing here in Safari v. 10.0.1.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
    // Nothing happens here in Safari. Scroll event is never fired.
});
```

EDIT: I had an issue with my CSS that fixed the problem. I had some old stuff for scroll snap points (which I don't need) that I forgot to delete from my CSS. On a div surrounding my content I had

```
height: 100vh;
```

So it makes sense that the scroll event on the window would not be fired, because I would be scrolling inside my div instead.